# Hotkey to send hero back to base

Tags: dota-2

I was thinking if it is possible to quickly send your hero back to the fountain by pressing a hotkey or something. This would be really useful when playing micro heavy heroes like Meepo or Chen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In dota 2, to be able to go back to the fountain with any heroes you need to own either a TP Scroll or Boots of Travel. If you have one of those in your inventory you can double tap the hotkey of the inventory slot to teleport to fountain. Hotkeys for inventory slot can be set in the parameters menu.

If your question concerns the action "Walk back to the fountain", there are none such command (unlike courier who has a "back to the fountain" action).

Comment: Yes I mean walking back. Well I guess I have to use the Minimap then.

Comment: @st0ph  
I play Meepo and I can tell that you get pretty quiclky used to right click the minimap to give order, but I agree that such command would be usefull

Comment: interesting. i am going to try to build a script for that.

Comment: @Wandang if you manage to do that I'd be intersted in seeing it ^_-

Comment: @jmfsg yeah but as you can see another user was faster. i did however improve his script a bit

Answer (score 8):

I improved User56743's script a bit (removed the drawbacks):

Defining leftclick, position of fountains and hero

```
alias "leftclick" "+sixense_left_click; -sixense_left_click"
alias "camRadiant" "dota_camera_setpos -6985 -6942 1243"
alias "camDire" "dota_camera_setpos 6878 5772 1238"
alias "camCenter" "+dota_camera_follow;+dota_camera_follow;-dota_camera_follow"
```

Defining what happens on buttonpress(`+myMoveRad`) and buttonrelease (`-myMoveRad`)

```
alias "+myMoveRad" "mc_move; camRadiant; leftclick"
alias "-myMoveRad" "camCenter"
alias "+myMoveDire" "mc_move; camDire; leftclick"
alias "-myMoveDire" "camCenter"

bind "B" "+myMoveRad"
bind "C" "+myMoveDire"
```

this code moves the camera to the desired fountain, leftclicks where the mouse currently is and moves the camera back to the hero without sticking to it.

### Technical detail:

the onpress (+) and onrelease (-) parts are important in this code because the execution of the `camCenter` part is faster then the `leftclick` part resulting in a move command at your original camera position (center) instead of the fountain.

Comment: Does this work with non-Sixense products?

Comment: "Products"? you mean another steam game? if so then i dont know. valve cooperates with six-sense to enable this feature for windows users. six-sense is available for other OS too but afaik valve did not yet implemented it for other OSs.

Comment: Oops, never mind. I thought it was a company that made things like gaming mice.

Comment: well they do build/promote mice and other input systems too as you can see on their homepage: http://sixense.com/dota2 . It seems to me that their system is just an emulation of a normal keyboard and mouse to enable their products/projects to work and dota integrated that layer. This layer can be used by anyone, not only their products. So the answer to your first comment is: yes

Comment: Okay, because I have it in [my autoexec.cfg](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/11264247), but it's not working.

Comment: Ok. First: You are using windows right?(just to make sure). Second: did you bind g and t in your ingame settings? to make sure those are available for your script you should do `unbind g` and `unbind t` at the start. I will test the script now

Comment: the script works for me. Does your file really called `autoexec.cfg`?

Comment: Weird, I tried starting the script with the unbind commands, but that didn't help. I finally decided to use `B` instead of `G` and it works now. I wonder what's wrong with binding to `G`?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14119/discussion-between-wandang-and-louis)

Answer (score 7):

I tried to make a quick script here it is:

```
alias +base "dota_camera_setpos -7008.000000 -7367.000000 1243.072876"

alias -base "dota_camera_center"

bind k "+base"
```

Drawbacks:

1. This doesn't cause your hero to move automatically, but only moves your camera to the fountain. You still have to manually right click or give the move command.
2. On releasing the button, in this case "k" the camera centers and follows the hero. Unless this is disabled by edge panning(move the mouse till the camera stop following the hero), you won't be able to press the button("k" in this case) and look at the fountain.

If anyone could improve or find a solution to these drawbacks, I'd much appreciate it. Hope it helped you. Edit: Replace "k" with the button of your choice.

Comment: You can probably add a "mouse2" in there, couldn't you? That'd right click for you, and all you'd have to do would be press "k" while having the mouse over the main screen. This also will only work for (presumably from the coordinates) the Radiant side.

Comment: There is also a way to store the current camera coordinates such that they can be recalled (so you could go to the base, click, then return to previous location all in a single macro), with the dota_camera_getpos console command.

Comment: Does it moove the camera to both fountain depending on your side ?

Comment: how can i store values that i get from those commands?