# Which HUD has the smallest map?

Tags: dota-2

I always die from accidentally clicking on the map while trying to get back, and running the wrong way, into certain death.

Which HUD has the smallest map, so I can have more world-space?

Comment: Often the case with me. Would be better if there is a key which sends a hero walking in the direction of the fountain

Comment: @MandeepJain i did a script for that: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/128460/hotkey-to-send-hero-back-to-base/137646#137646

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They all have the same map size, and If I recall correctly, you can't change it. However there is a console command :

*dota_minimap_misclick_time X*

X being the number of second that have to tick before you can click on the minimap. The default value is 0.2 sec but you can raise the value which result in less missclick since you have to hover the map longer before it becomes clickable

To enable the console in dota 2 follow those steps :

- Open your game library in Steam
- Right click on DotA 2
- Properties
- Tab "General"
- Click "Set launch option"
- Type in `-console`

Now when the game starts you will always have the console. This method however force you to type the command *dota_minimap_misclick_time X* every time you start the game. If you think that its annoying, you can write the command in a file that will be auto executed at every start of the game. Refer to [the following answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/152891/24592) to learn how to set up autoexec.cfg.

Comment: That sounds very helpful. How do you get to the console?

Comment: @Louis edited my answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, they all have the same size, and I believe I read that the game specifically does not render the portion of the map below the HUD to combat hacking (e.g. making the HUD transparent to give a larger view area and an unfair advantage).

You can, however, switch the minimap to the right hand side of your screen, which can be advantageous because the main directions of movement in dota are from bottom left (where the map is) to top right, since those are the two team bases.

Go to options, and I believe it's under "interface". It'll take a bit of getting used to, but will make it less likely you'll click on the map while running away.